# How to test that actor receives messages from scheduler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, akka.net

After I create a ActorSystem and a `WorkerActor` I schedule some message to be sent every 5 minutes:

```
_actorSystem.Scheduler.ScheduleTellRepeatedly(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 
    workerActor, new MyMessage(), Nobody.Instance);
```

How would one test this using `TestKit`?

I have found this article: https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/

The example "How do I test scheduled messages?" at the end of the article shows how to advance the virtual time so the test not waits X minutes. Unfortunately,  it actually tests that Actor ***sends*** messages on schedule not ***receives*** them.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730706/how-to-use-testkit-in-akka-net?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103148/akka-net-and-unit-tests?rq=1

Comment: @Nkosi, I saw those answers already. Do you want to say that what I am trying to achieve is impossible unless my WorkerActor sends out some messages? The problem here this is leaf actor that just do some work on schedule and does not communicate with any other actors. Even the sender of the message is `Nobody.Instance`